# Jquery.validate - single and/or multiple email address issue

Tags: jquery, validation, email

I have managed to get a normal form up and running and validated with jQuery.validate with no problem. What i'd like to do is change the email to field to be able to take a single or multiple emails.

Using posts from this website I have tried to implement something but am not having any luck.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("multiemail", function(value, element) {
 if (this.optional(element)) return true;
 var emails = value.split(/[;,]+/); // split element by , and ;
 valid = true;
 for (var i in emails) {
  value = emails[i];
  console.log(value); 
  valid = valid && jQuery.validator.methods.email.call(this, $.trim(value), element); }
  return valid;
  }
);

$('#send_file_email').validate({
 rules: {
  name: {
   minlength: 2,
   required: true
  },
  email_from: {
   required: true,
   email: true
  },
  email_to: {
   required: true,
   multiemail: true

  },
  subject: {
   minlength: 2,
   required: true
  },
 },
```

When I place traces through the added method, it seems to not run whenever I add a second email, but runs fine when one valid email is typed in.

I feel like I am making a basic coding error but I cannot see it for the life of me!

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C7572/1/

Comment: Yeah it does... must be some other code interfering... ill have a look, thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Did some testing using my work and your jsfiddle... when I removed type="email" from my input it worked fine. Makes sense now, thanks for your help